# redirecting in a new window by clicking on image

Tags: html, asp.net, redirect, new-window

I have got stuck in a wired problem on my project

I have made frames using iframe and called a page booking.aspx in it which has imagebutton in it i want to open a NEW WINDOW by onclick event of imagebutton and open a page called "booking.aspx?moviename" moviename has the name of movie from last page
i know we can open newwindow in htlm but i dont know how to send info from 1 page to another in it

in asp.net i know how to send info from 1 page to another but dont know how to open that page in new window

i am new to this form plz ask for addition info if required :)

Comment: Please show your effort

Comment: calm down and shape up your description. provide some code so that we can SEE what is going on.